# Why are results different when using aov_ez{afex} and Anova{car}, Type III SS in R?

Tags: r, anova, categorical-encoding

Hopefully, the answer to this question is simple.

Why do I get different results when I am using Anova from the car package and the aov_ez from the afex package?

```
library(car)
library(afex)

set.seed(100)

dv <-  runif(30,90,110)
factor_a <-  factor(rep(c("a","b"),15))
factor_b <-  factor(rep(c("f","m"),each=15))
id <- factor(1:30)
data <- data.frame(dv,factor_a,factor_b,id)

data$dv[data$factor_b=="f" & data$factor_a=="a"] <- data$dv[data$factor_b=="f" & data$factor_a=="a"] *1.05

aov_ez(dv="dv",between = c("factor_a","factor_b"), id="id",data=data )
Anova(lm(dv~factor_a*factor_b, data=data),type = "III")
```

Results are different in case of the main effect factor B:
Using aov_ez, the main effect is significant, using Anova, the main effect is not significant. How is that possible?
In both cases, there is a significant interaction and the F-values are very similar. But the F-values of the main effects differ.

```
>     aov_ez(dv="dv",between = c("factor_a","factor_b"), id="id",data=data )
Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: factor_a, factor_b
Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: dv
             Effect    df   MSE       F ges p.value
1          factor_a 1, 26 20.96  4.16 + .14     .05
2          factor_b 1, 26 20.96    0.55 .02     .46
3 factor_a:factor_b 1, 26 20.96 9.03 ** .26    .006
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

>     Anova(lm(dv~factor_a*factor_b, data=data),type = "III")
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: dv
                  Sum Sq Df   F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)        89775  1 4282.2927 < 2.2e-16 ***
factor_a             267  1   12.7159  0.001434 ** 
factor_b             147  1    7.0288  0.013478 *  
factor_a:factor_b    189  1    9.0269  0.005822 ** 
Residuals            545 26                        
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Because I am quite new using R, which of these two packages I should use. Does anyone know why the results differ?

Comment: Shouldn't `data$factor_a = "a"` be `data$factor_a == "a"`?

Comment: oh thank you! i didn't noticed that earlier. 

do you also have any idea why these two functions differ with respect to the results?

Comment: Did you try running the corrected code? Also, set the RNG seed so your results are reproducible.

Comment: hey kodiologist and thank you again for you comment. I did run it again with the corrected code and also set seed to 100. The outcome is especially interesting because now, using the car package, I have 2 significant main effects as well as a significant interaction (the only value that is identical with the output of the afex package function). 
MSE = 20.96 is also equal to 545/26 = 20.96, this can't be it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that you have a balanced between-subjects design with only dichotomous IVs, so the sum-of-squares type doesn't matter and  `Anova(lm(dv~factor_a*factor_b, data=data))` produces the same $p$-values as $t$-tests of regression coefficients:

```
> print(summary(lm(dv~factor_a*factor_b, data=data)))
[…]
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          105.933      1.619  65.439  < 2e-16 ***
factor_ab             -8.450      2.370  -3.566  0.00143 ** 
factor_bm             -6.282      2.370  -2.651  0.01348 *  
factor_ab:factor_bm   10.069      3.351   3.004  0.00582 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
[…]
```

So why does `aov_ez` give different $p$s? It seems that `aov_ez` codes the IVs with effects coding by default, rather than dummy coding as in base R's `lm`; the message `Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: factor_a, factor_b` is a warning of this. When we set `check.contrasts` to `FALSE`, `aov_ez` uses dummy coding and we get concordant $F$s and $p$s:

```
> print(aov_ez(dv="dv",between = c("factor_a","factor_b"), id="id",data=data, check_contrasts = F ))
Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: dv
             Effect    df   MSE        F ges p.value
1          factor_a 1, 26 20.96 12.72 ** .33    .001
2          factor_b 1, 26 20.96   7.03 * .21     .01
3 factor_a:factor_b 1, 26 20.96  9.03 ** .26    .006
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
Calculating Type 3 sums with contrasts != 'contr.sum' for: factor_a, factor_b, factor_a, factor_b
  Results likely bogus or not interpretable!
  You probably want check_contrasts = TRUE or options(contrasts=c('contr.sum','contr.poly'))
```

Why exactly the package author thinks that dummy coding in this situation makes the results "likely bogus or not interpretable" goes further into the weeds of ANOVA than I'm familiar with. But at least now we know what `aov_ez` is doing.

Comment: +1. Here is some reading: https://methodology.psu.edu/media/techreports/12-120.pdf and http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/1521-2015.pdf. Briefly, with dummy coding the "main effects" are not really ANOVA main effects (they are smth like effects of one factor at one fixed level of another factor).

Comment: thank you both, @Kodiologist and amoeba...both your answers are very helpful!